# iTunes Connect - The app name has already been used

Tags: app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect, I want to create an app called "Travelogue" but it says that the app name has been used.

After doing extensive searching on iTunes and the app store, I see no results which have the name 'Travelogue'

I also have not created an app with the name 'Travelogue' before; so, it could not be locked in.

What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps another developer created the app with that name but it has not yet been approved which is why it doesn't show up on the app store.  It might still be in initial development.  Searching on iTunes/app store would only show apps which have been released.